# Which site should I use for questions about hardware?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a question about ARM processors and thermal monitoring. I tried asking on Server Fault but it got closed as off topic. It certainly isn't a Stack Overflow question.

Where should I ask this type of questions?

Answer (score 7):

[Super User](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) is the place for hardware questions.

> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a question about …
>
> - computer hardware,
> - computer software, or
> - personal and home computer networking
>
> and it is not about …
>
> - programming and software development,
> - video games or consoles,
> - websites or web services like Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress,
> - electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones, except insofar as they interface with your computer,
> - issues specific to corporate IT support and networks,
> - asking for a shopping or product recommendation,
>
> … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

Comment: ARM processors ==> "it is not about [...] electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones, except insofar as they interface with your computer".  @ethrbunny better tell SU this processer is in a computer and not a smartphone...